# Firebase check if a user email has been verified

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a web application which uses React and Firebase as backend.
This application shows a list of users and, for each user, I wanna know if his email has been verified.
So,

How can I check if an user's email (given an email address) has been verified ?

I already tried to do som :

```html
firebase.auth().getUserByEmail(email).then((info)=>{
  console.log("sucessfully fetched info:" +info);
})
.catch(()=>console.log("error")
```

But I got error, something like 'getUserByEmail is not a function'

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth does not provide any APIs for a user to get any other user's profile data.  That would be a security problem - profile data is private in Firebase Auth.

What you'll have to do is write some code that updates a database with the information you want, and have your clients query that database instead.  How this happens in practice is entirely up to you.  Each user account is probably going to have to update the database with its own email verification status.